# Confused about the Kelvin wake pattern

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, dispersion, phase-velocity

What are the $v_{\text{phase}}$ and the $v_{\text{group}}$ in [Kelvin wakes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_wake_pattern)? Additionally there are tons of water waves combined to form the kelvin wake. How is it possible for the $v_{\text{group}}$ to be equal to half of $v_{\text{phase}}$, when there are different phase velocities?

Comment: Completely cool with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin_wake_pattern#Formation)?

Answer (score 2):

What is the problem? For deep water $\omega(k)=\sqrt{gk}$ so
$$
v_{\rm phase}= \frac{\omega}{k} =\sqrt{\frac g k}
$$
and
$$
v_{\rm group}= \frac{\partial\omega}{\partial k}= \frac 12 \sqrt{\frac g k}= \frac 12 v_{\rm phase}.
$$

Comment: In the first part pf the question, I meant vphase is the speed of what? Which wave? And the Vgroup is the speed of what? The whole kelvin wake pattern?

Comment: In the second part, I don't understand how can the Vphase be 2 times the Vgroup when the Vgroup is constant. Because we know that the kelvin wake is formed by combining millions of waves that have different wavelengths so that they have different Vphase

Comment: @7Wdev As you can see from the above relations, both $v_{\text{phase}}$ and $v_{\text{group}}$ depend on the wavenumber $k$ which is inversely proportional to a *specific* wavelength. Hence, no matter how many wave lengths are created by the source moving across the deep water, this relation of the phase velocity being twice the group velocity holds for each fixed wavelength separately.

Comment: @Amit that's illogical, when u change k by taking another wavelength you change the vphase and by that you get a different vgroup from the relation above

Comment: @7Wdev The wave lengths that will be visible depend on the speed of the source. Some wave lengths will be greatly diminished due to destructive interference while others amplified due to constructive interference. It seems to me then what you may really want to ask is how this interference process results only in a very specific range of visible wave lengths. The relation between those wave lengths and their phase and group velocities should already be clear to you from this answer

Comment: Maybe you're correct, the problem that each source that I visited provides a different explaination to what really happens and how all the proccess of forming the kelvin wake works

Comment: @7Wdev There is a very nice simulation and explanation [here](https://observablehq.com/@rreusser/dispersion-in-water-surface-waves). It's really fun to play with this simulation. Tip: try reducing the gravity to $1$, I found that the wakes are most easily visible this way even for low duck speeds ;) It can intuitively help to see how circular water waves overlap from many positions to create the resulting Kelvin wake.

Comment: I watched this video and it seemed obvious [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=95sQcSulRFM) , but what I dont understand why water waves repeat themselves?, why does the boat create train of waves in different wavelenghts?
also where does the circles disappear he had only combined the wakes.

Comment: @7Wdev Best if you do an experiment. Fill yourself a water bath say, and disturb the water with a stick, dipping it only once and moving it out. This creates a vibration around that point that repeats several times until dissipating, but until then every up and down motion around this point will create a circular wave, of diminishing amplitudes

Comment: Do you understand a Mach-cone shockwave is formed by a supersonic bullet?  You need to understand this, and combine that understanding with the fact that however slow the boat is going, it is faster than *some* collection of wave phase velocities. The wake is the sum of all  the Mach wedges.